# How to alter query of block inside a panel

Tags: views, panels

I have a View that contains many blocks. I want to customize the query for a specific block.
I have tried `views_query_alter()` hook and `$view->query->add_where`, but in this case the query will be modified for all blocks.

Any idea of how to customize the query using `add_where` for a specific block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `$view->current_display` in your `hook_views_query_alter` to alter the query differently for each different block.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by checking $view->build_info['title'] ... thanks